# Unsubscribing in RxJS 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

I have a test and it works, but if I try to set active to a different value it will break the test.  So I wish to unsubscribe `a` (The current active Observable) before doing any other testing:

```
let a:Observable<Todo> = store.observeActive(); 
a.subscribe(active=> {
  expect(active).toEqual(todo1);
});
a.unsubscribe();
```

It looks as if RxJS 6 no longer has `unsubscribe()` ... Thoughts?

### Follow Up

So we unsubscribe on the `Subscription` reference, but is there a reason why the designers did not put the `unsubscribe` method on the object instance that is subscribing?

Comment: `subscribe` is supposed to return an subscription object, that you can `unsubscribe`, see [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subscription.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let a:Observable<Todo> = store.observeActive(); 
const subscription = a.subscribe(active=> {
  expect(active).toEqual(todo1);
});
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Subscribe returns a subscription, and you unsubscribe with the subscription.